# Are my saves transferable to another Wii?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I have tried to move several Wii saves from one console to another in the past with an SD card, and some games seem to have disabled this feature.  I am currently traveling and would like to start playing Skyward Sword, but I want to make sure I can offload this save and take it home with me when the time comes.

For example, Mario Kart Wii, Several Pokemon games, Super Smash Bros Brawl, etc., these saves are non-copyable.

Are Skyward Sword saves allowed to be copied from one Wii to another, within the same region?

Comment: I doubt copying saves would work for any of the Pokemon games.  Otherwise it would be too easy to cheat.  "Did I just trade away my Mew? _[restores previous save]..._ Nope."

Comment: Why not start a game, save, and then try to copy the save?

Comment: I don't have the game yet, considering buying for the holiday weekend if indeed I can transfer the save back home later this week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.  *Skyward Sword* games saves can be copied to an SD card.  They take up one block of memory.**

Keep in mind that that game saves are locked to your region.  [From Wii Save](http://wiisave.com/faq/index.php):

> We're nearly positive you can't use foreign saves on your Wii. We're still looking in to a way to do it, but so far, it's not looking good. You'll most likely have to stick to your own region when swapping saves.

As long as the Wii you use is in the same region as your Wii at home, you should be fine.

I've downloaded a couple of Wii save files from that site, and never had a problem.  I've never tried to copy between consoles, though.  **When copying saves, you have to delete any existing save files from the destination before the Wii will copy anything.**  It won't overwrite.

Comment: The reason I ask the question is obviously because SOME saves cannot, such as Mario Kart Wii, certain pokemon games (maybe all), so I just wanted to confirm that you can actually do it with Skyward Sword saves.

Comment: Have you been able to copy a save to an SD card?  Or are you trying to find out if it will even work before you try it?

Comment: Indeed, I haven't even purchased the game yet, but I won't buy it if it doesn't work, I can wait until I return from my trip.  It is no fun to have to start all over again after traversing your way through Skyloft  :)

Comment: @kazzamalla: You always have the option of taking your Wii with you.  You could just swap it when you get there and play.  When you're ready to go home, swap it back and you still have your saves on _your_ Wii.

Comment: I can confirm that this works (I just did it). One thing though: after copying the block from my SD card to Wii memory, I had to reboot the Wii before the saved game was actually recognized by Skyward Sword.

Answer (score 3):

Generally save moving/copying is prevented for two reasons:

1. The game has an online component that needs to remain "locked" to the Wii it was started on. Mario Kart Wii and SSBB have this requirement.
2. The game is a Pokémon game. Moving saves leads to potential copying of saves leads to duplication of Pokémon. Not something they want you to do. (I think they even put locks on the GameCube Pokémon games because of this but I'm not sure.)

Zelda games fit neither of these criteria, so there shouldn't be any reason for them to be save-locked.

Answer (score 3):

It does allow you to copy and move to SD card. Just confirmed. I will attempt to play on another Wii later tonight. I don't see why it wouldn't play though if I can move it. Will be upset if I can't! Haha. Guess I'll be playing Skyrim, MW3, or AC Revolations if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you soft-modded your wii and have the Homebrew Channel installed, you can backup **ALL** of your Miis/Saves using this wii channel,
http://wiibrew.org/wiki/SaveGame_Manager_GX
Works great!